# Teamcity trigger if the branch is being created/deleted

Tags: git, bitbucket, teamcity

In TeamCity, there are two builds for which you need to configure triggers: one should start immediately after creating any branch in BitBucket, the second should start after deleting any branch. In this case, both builds must register the name of the created or deleted branch.

As I understand it, this feature is not provided out of the box in either TeamCity or BitBucket. Tell me, please, whether it is possible to do this at all in theory somehow.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible without custom scripts, at least not in TeamCity. May I ask what kind of workflow you would like to attach to the deletion of a branch? I've never come across that requirement so it seems strange to me to want to react to that.

Comment: It looks like you can set a parameter `teamcity.vcsTrigger.runBuildInNewEmptyBranch` to `true` to let it trigger on branch creation. See this thread for more details: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-43606. Regarding the branch deletion, that's a very unusual requirement. The CI server is usually expected to checkout the branch in question, but in case of a deleted branch it doesn't exist. What's the use case behind this?

Comment: I also don't understand the deletion workflow. I can possibly fathom on branch creation, but "any" branch seems like overkill. Perhaps it should be filtered to be only certain branches. As someone who regularly pushes out my WIP branches for testing and/or backup purposes, I wouldn't like losing the ability to do this.

Comment: Developers upload the entire branch to the server every time it appears, and work locally. Don't ask why, it's a long story and it makes sense :) That's why we wanted the build to be activated when creating a branch, which pumps out this branch. At the moment, the build is activated manually.